# Qt and qwt installation on ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS: how to connect them?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qwt

I installed Qt on Ubuntu via the Qt installer downloaded from the official web page.
I developed part of my application and I now need to add graphs, so I tried to install qwt: I found quite easy to do it via the package manager (apt-get). Unfortunately it is not automatically recognized by the Qt I installed. Someone could explain me how to tell Qt to detect the qwt library?

I also tried to install Qt via the package manager, and this time qwt works, but it is an older version, and my application is not working well anymore.

Here is my pro file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2019-06-04T19:53:08
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Analisi
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

CONFIG += c++11
CONFIG += qwt

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \
        measure.cpp

HEADERS += \
        gnuplot-iostream.h \
        mainwindow.h \
        measure.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

LIBS += -lboost_iostreams -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

**edit:**
I've added the following code to my .bashrc file:

```sh
#qwt path for qt designer
#QT_PLUGIN_PATH="/usr/local/qwt-6.1.4/plugins/:$QT_PLUGIN_PATH"
QT_PLUGIN_PATH="/usr/local/qwt-6.1.4/plugins/"
QMAKEFEATURES="/usr/local/qwt-6.1.4/features:$QMAKEFEATURES"
export QT_PLUGIN_PATH
export QMAKEFEATURES
```

now it is working but only when I start qtcreator from a terminal.

Comment: Qt doesn't need to connect to it. Your code needs to link to it properly. How are you compiling? Are you using Cmake/Qmake?

Comment: read https://qwt.sourceforge.io/qwtinstall.html

Comment: I think is not the good answer but I know only that I'm using the "run" button on Qt Creator (installed via the Qt installer). I am quite new in Qt, do you know where I can find the information you need?
I am not able to see the qwt widgets in the QtDesigner, so I don't know how to use them.

Comment: thanks @eyllanesc, in the configuration file it says "When using the path below QWT_INSTALL_PREFIX you need to add $${QWT_INSTALL_PREFIX}/plugins to QT_PLUGIN_PATH in the runtime environment of designer/creator". Do you know how can I do this?

Comment: Where does it say that?

Comment: In the "qwtconfig.pri" file, that the guide asks to read inside "configuration" section

Comment: @eyllanesc I tryed to follow the guide but I had no success: the installation seems working,  but it is still not detected by Qt Creator

Comment: @Stefano mmm How do you check that Qt Creator doesn't detect it? can you show your .pro

Comment: I copied and past the "libqwt_designer_plugin.so" in the standalone application path, and now it is recognized by qtdesigner. Unfortunately, when I try to use it, I have an error 
"/ui_mainwindow.h:32: error: qwt_plot.h: No such file or directory
 #include "qwt_plot.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~"
I guess this was not the right way to do it...

Comment: @Stefano can you please extend your post with the content of .pro file?

Comment: @tema I did it, I hope it is more useful now

Comment: @Stefano did you try to re-run `qmake` after you added `CONFIG+=qwt` to the .pro file?

Comment: @tema I don't know how to do it. I simply run with "play" button in qtcreator

Comment: @Stefano in the menubar you can find 'Build' button. Press it, select Clean all, press it again, select Run qmake, than you can try with 'play' button

Comment: @Stefano did it help?

Comment: @tema no, but i found a solution. I will write as soon as I have the time to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and I hope that it could be useful also for other people. Mainly, you need to follow the guide https://qwt.sourceforge.io/qwtinstall.html.

The problem then is to tell to QtCreator where it can find your library. This can be done creating to environment variables. This is explained in the guide but there is not a clear indication on how to do it on Ubuntu. To create the variables, and made evrithing works when you lunch Qt from the gnome launcher, you need to modify the file "/etc/environment" adding this two lines:

```
QT_PLUGIN_PATH="/usr/local/qwt-6.1.4/plugins/:$QT_PLUGIN_PATH"
QMAKEFEATURES="/usr/local/qwt-6.1.4/features:$QMAKEFEATURES"
```

This in my case solved the problem.
Note that you may need to modify the path accordingly if you installed the Qwt libraries in a custom location.